# sending messages via twilio using composer

Tags: php, html, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am trying to send messages via twilio.
I was trying to send it normally by running its php source file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeqTN.png)

[image]

//this image shows the twilio source file
but it didn't work either.
so i downloaded composer and its again not working??.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIMDe.png)

[image]

//this shows the composer
Am i forgetting something?

i need this to complete a project.
other online sites are not sending messages on time.
if u know any good one(site) ...pls let me know.

Comment: So, what error do you get? Can you be a bit more specific about what is not working?

Comment: For sms, you shall also try [plivo](http://www.plivo.com)

Comment: thanku guys.. but it worked.. after downloading curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after downloading curl it started working properly.